# If I join two tables with date fields, how do I ensure that I pull the data from table b, for the date from table a?

Tags: sql, sas

I have two tables I am doing an inner join on.
The first table has a date, the second has data about individuals and trailing data based on the date in that table.
If I join the two tables, will the data pulled for table B have info for the date in table A?
Thanks

I tried to pull the data for table b using the date in table a but I'm not sure which date my trailing data about players at a casino is referencing.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: A guide how to ask a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It is hard to understand your question. If your are working with two tables and your concern is that they both have a column of the same name, make sure you qualify the column names with their table names. In the result you can use alias names to make it obvious which column we are looking at. E.g. `select bought.date as bought_date, sold.date as sold_date from bought join sold using (item_no)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you inner join on equality of the date variable it will not matter because the date values in the matching records will be the same.

Many times a schema design has a master record, unique for some key, and related satellite, or detail, records of which there may be many records. Suppose your data has

```
Master
[playerid] [date] [other fields...]

Detail
[playerid] [date] [table] [time_start] [time_end] [other fields...]
```

An inner join for a player on a date would be

```
  select MASTER.*, DETAIL.*
  from MASTER
  inner join DETAIL
  on MASTER.playerid = DETAIL.playerid
  and MASTER.date = DETAIL.date
  ;
```

The [date] field in the result set is a matching criteria, so you won't have mixed up dates and details.